# How does JavaScript store the (.length) property in a variable?

Tags: javascript

I am confused about the `arr.length` property. I know that is has been already discussed here but my question is a bit different. If I am creating a string like

`var str = "Hello!";`

i can access it with the `str.length` property and get returned the length. The `length` property, will it always be created by creating a new variable or is it a reference to anywhere?

Comment: When you create an `array`, `string` etc it will have `length` property.

Comment: You mean it will be created like a constructor?

Comment: String and array is an object and it has a property length.

Comment: Hi @joshaux, properties are not created everytime you call it. When you create the string, it will contain already this information then, for you to retrieve any time you need it.

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies! So the property will be created by creating i.e. a new string object and i can then be accesed every time i call it?

Answer (score 2):

The length property is a property that belongs the the Array or String object. So anything that has the type Array or String, will have this property available. Its bound to the prototype of these objects.

Edit:

Thanks to the comment below i've come to the realization that the length property doesnt only belong to the Ojects I mentioned above. Anyways, to answer the OP's question length is a property to these native Objects.

Comment: That's technically not true, since it belongs to every standard built-in object.

Comment: @briosheje so an object has a .length property? For as far as i know i can only use it on strings and arrays.

Comment: Actually no, it's worth to note, however, that every built-in function object (sorry, missed that part) has a length property: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-standard-built-in-objects. Functions have a length too: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function.length as well as arrays http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-get-%typedarray%.prototype.length or even function generators http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-generatorfunction.length . In a nutshell, it doesn't ONLY belong to these :).

Comment: @briosheje I have edited the answer. Making clear that it doesnt only apply to arrrays and strings

Comment: if I am creating a string like i.e var string = "Hello world!" than I created a object, not a primitive datatype "string" is that correct?

Comment: @joshaux Maybe you've heard people say that in Javascript everything is an object. So yeah when you create a string you actually create an instance of the String object. This object has properties/methods (functions) like length and others. All primitive datatypes are objects in javascript.